# Reactive Programming with RxJS - can this scroll function be simplified?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm pretty new to reactive programming (and RxJS) and all these operators are heavy to understand.

Anyway, I've successfully written this function that handles scrolling of the document while dragging something. I now wonder if this can be simplified.

Basically, onMouseDown I need to check the position of the mouse every 10ms and I need the updated `clientY` when the mouse moved, thats why I setup an `Rx.Oberservable.interval(10)` which I combine with the mouseMove observer. This will scroll the page, whether you move your mouse or not (as intended).

Here's the code:

```
handleWindowScrollOnDrag() {
    var dragTarget = this.getDOMNode()
    var scrollTarget = document.body
    var wHeight = window.innerHeight
    var maxScroll = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - wHeight

    // Get the three major events
    var mouseup   = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');
    var mousemove = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
    var mousedown = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(dragTarget, 'mousedown');

    var mousedrag = mousedown.flatMap(function (md) {
        var y = scrollTarget.scrollTop
        var multiplier = 1

        // Scroll every 10ms until mouseup when we can
        var intervalSource = Rx.Observable.interval(10).takeUntil(mouseup);

        // Get actual clientY until mouseup
        var movement = mousemove.map(function (mm) {
            return {
                y: mm.clientY
            };
        }).takeUntil(mouseup);

        return Rx.Observable
            .combineLatest(movement, intervalSource, function (s1) {
                multiplier = 1

                if (s1.y < 100 && y >= 0) {
                    if (s1.y < 75) multiplier = 3;
                    if (s1.y < 50) multiplier = 5;
                    if (s1.y < 25) multiplier = 10;
                    if (s1.y < 15) multiplier = 20;
                    y -= (1 * multiplier)
                }

                if (s1.y > wHeight - 100 && y <= (maxScroll)) {
                    if (s1.y > wHeight - 75) multiplier = 3;
                    if (s1.y > wHeight - 50) multiplier = 5;
                    if (s1.y > wHeight - 25) multiplier = 10;
                    if (s1.y > wHeight - 15) multiplier = 20;
                    y += (1 * multiplier)
                }

                return {
                    y: y
                };
        });
    });

    // Update position
    this.subscription = mousedrag.subscribe(function (pos) {
        document.body.scrollTop = pos.y
    });

},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the extra `takeUntil`s you only need one on the `movement` stream, since the `combineLatest` operator will clean up and dispose of all the underlying subscriptions when it completes.

Next, you can remove some extra state by using `.scan` to manage accumulated state instead of closure variables.

You can also simplify the event body by simply passing the mouse move's `y` value instead of incurring the overhead of an object allocation in both the `map` and the `combineLatest` operators.

Finally, I would change to use `.withLatestFrom` instead of `combineLatest`. Since you are already essentially polling at 100 fps with interval `combineLatest` would emit even faster if the mouse was moving at the same time.

As a side note, while I am not terribly familiar with how DOM scrolling works (and I don't actually know how well your code works in the wild), spamming the page's scroll value faster than the actual render rate of the page seems like overkill. It might be better to lower the interval rate and use something like `jQuery.animate` to smooth the scrolling in between.

;tldr

```
handleWindowScrollOnDrag() {
  var dragTarget = this.getDOMNode()
  var scrollTarget = document.body;
  var wHeight = window.innerHeight;
  var maxScroll = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - wHeight;

  // Get the three major events
  var mouseup   = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');
  var mousemove = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
  var mousedown = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(dragTarget, 'mousedown');

  var mousedrag = mousedown.flatMap(function (md) {
      // Scroll every 10ms until mouseup when we can
      var intervalSource = Rx.Observable.interval(10, Rx.Scheduler.requestAnimationFrame);

      return intervalSource
          .takeUntil(mouseup)
          .withLatestFrom(mousemove, function (s1, s2) {
              return s2.clientY;
           })
           .scan(scrollTarget.scrollTop, function(y, delta) { 
              var multiplier = 1;

              if (delta  < 100 && y >= 0) {
                  if (delta < 75) multiplier = 3;
                  if (delta < 50) multiplier = 5;
                  if (delta < 25) multiplier = 10;
                  if (delta < 15) multiplier = 20;
                  y -= (1 * multiplier);
              }

              if (delta > wHeight - 100 && y <= (maxScroll)) {
                  if (delta > wHeight - 75) multiplier = 3;
                  if (delta > wHeight - 50) multiplier = 5;
                  if (delta > wHeight - 25) multiplier = 10;
                  if (delta > wHeight - 15) multiplier = 20;
                  y += (1 * multiplier);
              }

              return y;
        });
  });

  // Update position
  this.subscription = mousedrag.subscribe(function (pos) {
      document.body.scrollTop = pos;
  });

},
```

**Edit**

A mistake in the original actually allows one to simplify the code even further. You can remove the `movement` stream all together (and with it an extra call to `map`) by passing `mousemove` to `withLatestFrom` and using that result selector to grab the `clientY`

Additionally I added where you would likely want to add a scheduler if you were trying to synchronize `interval` with the render loop of the page, though I would still say you probably want to use 15ms (60fps) rather than 10ms, it again comes down to how the scroll rendering is done.

*If* setting the scroll position will only be updated at the end of each render loop then it will work fine. However, if it greedily recomputes after every `set` then it would be better to have an intermediary like `React` to write to Virtual DOM first rather than flushing all changes directly to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and tipps!

I've tried out your suggested code but one part is weird, `var movement = mousemove.map(function (mm) { return mm.clientY; });` this actually still returns the whole `MouseEvent`. I had to change the part where it says `return s2` to `return s2.clientY`. Got an idea why? Otherwise it works :)

About the requestAnimationFrame optimisation: I had the same idea already, and I saw there is a `Rx.Scheduler.requestAnimationFrame`. But I am not sure on how do add this.

Comment: @MartinBroder Good catch! You are correct, it was because I was still passing in the `mousemove` to the `withLatestFrom`. It turns out this is actually more desirable since you can use the `selector` function from `withLatestFrom` and save yourself an additional `map` operation. Edited with that and some points about scheduling.

Comment: hey @paulpdaniels, I can not thank you enough!  played around a bit more and it looks like .`observeOn(Rx.Sched...frame)` does the same when I add that to the intervalSource, is that correct? As far as I understand, it would overwrite the source scheduler. I think your way of doing it is just shorter, am I right?

Comment: @MartinBroder you are very welcome! `observerOn` actually _reschedules_ the events, they'll still get produced just as fast because it won't supersede the original `scheduler`. In this case with `interval`, by adding the `scheduler` argument you are controlling the speed of _generation_ instead. Also `interval` makes use of recursive scheduling it will have a smaller memory footprint (though in most cases this is a minor point).